# Show kebab case text in the url but actually send the request to an id which is illegible

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, routes, try-catch

When the user clicks on 'read more', the browser goes to a page with a url like this=>
https://example.com/stories/629217f1e70717debf9ff029 (the last parameter is the object id in the database). Say the topic of the story is 'Lorem ipsum', I want the url to show https://example.com/stories/lorem-ipsum and not the previous one. Problem is that I get the story id with req.params.id and then render the page. Is there any way I can show latter with the same functionality as the former?

```
router.get("/gp/:Id", ensureAuth, async (req, res) =>{try {
ab = await XXX.find({
  id: req.params.Id,
  status: "public",
}).lean();


res.render("aFile", {
  ab,
  
 title: ab[0].title,
})}catch (error) {
console.error(error);
res.render("/error/500");}});
```

Comment: if the title is unique then you can find the story with the title

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using the params and the *id* key or change it to *topic*. Just make sure the topic is unique; add a unique constraint on the *topic* field to the database table (or collection in case you are using mongo)

You can easily convert kebab case (lorem-ipsum) to normal string (lorem ipsum)

```
router.get("/gp/:topic", ensureAuth, async (req, res) => {

    // convert the kebab case to normal string (lorem-ipsum -> lorem ipsum)
    let topicString = req.params.topic.replace('-',' ');

    // We want to ignore capitalization to match the title, so use regex as shown below
    try {
        ab = await XXX.find({
            title: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${topicString}$`, 'i') },
            status: "public",
        }).lean();
        res.render("aFile", {
            ab,
            title: ab[0].title,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.render("/error/500");}
});
```